# Running two thinking sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Ok so i have two rails application on my server and both apps use thinking sphinx and all seems good with one app. when i do

```
rake ts:start RAILS_ENV=production
Started successfully (pid 9943).
```

but when i do it on the other app i get

```
rake ts:start RAILS_ENV=production --trace
** Invoke ts:start (first_time)
** Invoke thinking_sphinx:start (first_time)
** Invoke thinking_sphinx:app_env (first_time)
** Execute thinking_sphinx:app_env
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
Jammit Warning: Asset compression disabled -- Java unavailable.
Jammit Warning: No assets match 'public/stylesheets/public.css'
** Execute thinking_sphinx:start
Failed to start searchd daemon. Check /var/www/projects/log/searchd.log.
Failed to start searchd daemon. Check /var/www/projects/log/searchd.log
** Execute ts:start
```

they are both using different ports....any idea...also i checked the log file here `/var/www/projects/log/searchd.log` and its blank ...any idea what to do...i have tried almost everything

Comment: i think that it should be possible according to this: http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/common_issues.html#multiple are you sure that you are looking at the right log? i think that there is a different process spawned by the rake task. what does ps aux say? did you try cleaning up the pid-files?

Comment: i looked at this one /var/www/projects/log/searchd.log also how do i clean up the pid-files

Comment: by deleting them. most of the times, you find them in the tmp folder.

Answer (score 0):

rake ts:start starts your sphinx daemon. If you want your apps to share the same search engine, you should only do ts:start once. and both apps should work.